# how to prevent install of other product

Tags: wix

The RTM version of the product was shipped with Wix installer WITHOUT Upgrade element.
 Now we are going to ship update for it.
How can we now prevent downgrade of new version of the product by the RTM version?

Answer (score 2):

I wonder how you plan to upgrade the RTM version now. As long as there's no UpgradeCode in it initially, you don't have much options. For instance, you could add a registry search plus appropriate launch condition to prevent running update until the user uninstalls RTM manually.

The only way to prevent downgrade I can think of seems quite strange to me. If the ProductCode of the update stays the same as of RTM, then the attempt to install RTM after update will fail saying the product is already installed. But if you decide to go with major upgrade approach (where you'll have to change ProductCode for each new build), this won't work...

These thoughts above don't claim to be an exhaustive answer, but probably it will direct you towards the way to go somehow...

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - you cant.

Your best solution is to effectively release a new (fixed) product, and also change the installation location.

I faced the same problem a number of years ago and ended up writing a custom tool that would remove all traces of all versions of the application. It wasn't pretty, but it was the only viable solution that didn't require quadrupling our support staff.